# Minimal graph over convex domain is area-minimizing

Tags: reference-request, dg.differential-geometry, curves-and-surfaces, minimal-surfaces

I am looking for a reference stating that

> If a graph $z=f(x,y)$ over a convex domain $D$ is minimal, then it is area-minimizing.

- 5.4.18 in Federer's "Geometric measure theory" and Lemma 1.1. in Colding--Minicozzi's "A Course in Minimal Surfaces" state that it is true *with respect to $D\times \mathbb R$*.
- 6.1 in Morgan's  "Geometric measure theory" states it right, but (at least formally) the proof only shows that it is area-minimizing among oriented surfaces.

Comment: A naive question: What is a "minimal graph"?

Comment: Probably the "minimal graph" is defined as a solution of the non-linear PDE which is called the "minimal surface equation in non-parametric form"?

Comment: If you look below Corollary 1.2 in Colding Minicozzi's book they prove what you are asking by observing projecting to the cylinder is distance non-increasing map as the cylinder is a convex region).

Comment: That being said, the CM argument uses a calibration so doesn't that restrict its applicability to oriented surfaces?

Comment: @RBega2 Yes calibration works for oriented surface. The proof I see requires modifying the surface into oriented one with less area and then applying calibration. I did not see such proof written. (Maybe I missed a simpler argument.)

Comment: I think orientability follows from embededness as I explain in the comment below.

Comment: @MohammadGhomi The issue is to establish the existence of a minimizer in the class of of all orientable and non-orientable surfaces (otherwise there might be non-orientable competitors that don't satisfy any equation).  You can do this by working with mod 2 currents, but its not exactly elementary...

Comment: @MohammadGhomi to make it orientable one has to work a bit (more than you did in your answer). For example after mapping the surface into the cylinder you might pass to the "upper boundary" of set bounded by the obtained surface with self-intersections.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin You can also take the orientation double cover as this is homologous to twice the minimal graph and so the calibration argument implies that the area of the double cover is greater than twice that of the graph.

Comment: @RBega2 Don't you get zero?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that we have a fixed contour $\Gamma$ which is a graph over $\partial D$, and you want to show that the minimal graph spanned by $\Gamma$ is area minimizing.

First, by the maximum principle (with respect to vertical planes), the interior of any (compact) minimal surface spanned by $\Gamma$ has to lie in the interior of $D\times R$. Then using Alexandrov's reflection principle, with respect to horizontal planes, I think that one can show that the surface must be a graph over $D$. Then the result should follow from the references you cite.

In short, I am not aware of an explicit reference, but I think what you want should be a straight forward application of maximum principal and Alexandrov's method of moving planes.

Comment: Thank you --- I know how to prove it --- I just wanted a reference. (This should be a classical statement.)

Comment: As you may also know, I think that the moving plane argument here also shows that any minimal surface bounded by $\Gamma$ should be embedded, and therefore orientable, as it will divide $D\times R$ into two regions. So I think that one may assume orientability.

Comment: In this case you use existence of minimal surface (which is too much for the problem).